# Angular material Sticky column more than 1 column

Tags: angular7

im curently using angular ver 7 with angular cli and also angular material the lastest version

im get to the point when using the angular table with sticky column position

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="address" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

but when im serve it in the browser the sticky column all mess up,
there is some space beetween them so when im scroll to the right, the animation seems so off

it is the right way to use 2 sticky?

Answer (score 8):

Solved but in a clumsy way. The Angular 7 material table columns require percentage width positioning to be correctly aligned. Anyways I ended up giving fixed width to columns which are sticky from `.scss` file *e.g. * in your case

```css
.mat-col-name 
{
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px 
}
.mat-col-address 
{
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Notice that left has to be positioned exactly. This along with sticky tag on these two columns in the HTML template made it work properly for me.

**EDIT:**
In newest version of Angular you need to use **.mat-column**.

```css
.mat-column-name 
{
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px 
}
.mat-column-address 
{
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It is nice solution, but does not work for <th> elements. At least for me, I do not know why.

Comment: You're a life saver, I already did this and forgot why we did this. Now my table is broken again after upgrading to Angular 11. Remembered that I had a similar setup in my table and the left value is not being set correctly after upgrade. 

I haven't fixed it yet, but this answer pointed the right direction. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Perfect solution to me in Angular 11, at first is wasn't working but after analysing the css I understand that it was **.mat-column-name**. +1

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue. The sticky columns are collapsing and there's weird spacing between columns caused by the sticky attribute. This means when you scroll across the table, there's an accordion effect on sticky column sizes and the content on the lower/non sticky scrolling column is showing up under the top/sticky columns.

**Solution:**

Set *min-width* and *max-width* on each sticky column to be the same value - I used px.

Comment: This worked for td elements, but not for th... this is very weird... is there an open github issue for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in early stages of your project I would suggest you to upgrade your angular/meterial version and use [latest material feature for sticky columns](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-complex-flex) which is working great with multi sticky column/rows

Answer (score 0):

I work around that by overriding sticky css and use sticky as attribute too. It works for me in my case with its three sticky headers

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky class="mat-col-name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-col-name"> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="mat-col-name"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="address" sticky class="mat-col-address">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  class="mat-col-address"> Address</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="mat-col-address"> {{element.address}} </td>
</ng-container>

css:
.mat-col-name {
  width: 100px;
  top: 56px;
  z-index: 101;
  left: 0px;
  position: sticky;
}
.mat-col-address {
  left: 100px !important;
  width: 100px;
  top: 56px;
  z-index: 101;
  position: sticky;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using sticky for 3 columns, in the Angular material table.
I was finding a distorted view for sticky columns with added white space within them, this was because of the inbuilt CSS property of the sticky attribute. In my local, I didn't give any left or width CSS in code, but ongoing to DOM it was taking extra left space.

So I solved this using the below CSS by overriding the CSS of the sticky attribute.

**HTML:**

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="level" class="mat-col-levelDefault " sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Level </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.level}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.mat-col-levelDefault {
    left: 200px !important;
    width: 100px;
    top: 56px;
    z-index: 101;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `updateStickyColumnStyles()` after your table rendered and appropriate events emitted. Following code may not work depending on your setup.

```js
class A implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild(MatTable) public table!: MatTable<T>;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.table.updateStickyColumnStyles();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of just writing `sticky`, prefer writing `[sticky]="true"` at both positions, that should probably do. Rest the angular material will auto adjust.

**Code Below:-**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name" [sticky]="true">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="address" [sticky]="true">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: In terms of Angular, "sticky" and "[sticky]='true' " are equivalent. No way, that this could solve the problem.